# CRC 32 Does not work

Tags: c++

Hello i found a C++ implementation but it does not work. Here:

```
unsigned int crc32(unsigned char* message) {
    int i, j;

    unsigned int byte, crc, mask;

    i = 0;

    crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    while(message[i] != 0) {
     byte = message[i];
     crc = crc ^ byte;
    for(j=7; j>=0; j--){
     for(j=0; j>= 0; j--) {
      mask = -(crc & 1);
      crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320 & mask);
        }
        i = i + 1;
       }

    return ~crc;

 }
}

int main()
{
unsigned char a='a';
crc32(&a);

cout<return 0;
```

It says unary operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned.

When i delete the minus it does not give me a true CRC code.

Comment: What's that: `cout<return 0;` ?

Comment: I write it wrong actually there is not a thing like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This `crc32` function calls for null-terminated message, so passing pointer to `char` variable is bad.
- The line `cout<return 0;` doesn't make sense.
- There is conflict of loop variable between `for(j=7; j>=0; j--){` and `for(j=0; j>= 0; j--) {`. Remove the inner loop because it is one-time loop and it need not be a loop.
- The lines `i = i + 1;` and `return ~crc;` are in wrong place. You should format your code properly.
- The compiler seems hated to use `-(crc & 1)` to obtain `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

unsigned int crc32(unsigned char* message) {
    int i, j;

    unsigned int byte, crc;

    i = 0;

    crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    while(message[i] != 0) {
        byte = message[i];
        crc = crc ^ byte;
        for(j=7; j>=0; j--){
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (crc & 1 ? 0xEDB88320 : 0);
        }
        i = i + 1;

    }
    return ~crc;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char a[] = {'a', 0};
    cout << crc32(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It still says "unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned"

Comment: It seems because unary minus operator is applied to unsigned type and the result is used as unsigned number. Updated.

Comment: I want to read a file and calculate its crc32. Can you help me to modify the code?

Comment: This code takes chars from an array and calculates its crc. So, i need to read a file put the information in array and calculate its crc again. Is there a better solution?